The tolerance used to determine vector3d equality and the length of vector3d
I use a tolerance=1e-10 to check whether two vector3ds are equal, using following function is_same:
bool is_same(const vector3d& x, const vector3d& y) {
  var delta = x-y;
  return delta.length() < tolerance; // tolerance is 1e-10
}

But here comes a situation that I can't fix it. I have a class called lineSegments,
struct lineSegments {
   vector3d s, e; // s means start point, e means end point
}

When I calculate the intersection of two lineSegments. I used equation (e1-s1)*k1+s1 = (e2-s2)*k2+s2 to get k1 and k2, so the intersection point is (e1-s1)*k1+s1.
But when the two lineSegments like that:
auto l1 = lineSegments{
    {639482584.0, 2115435624.0, 0},    // s1
    {1658825857.0, 1245760131.0, 0}};  // e1
auto l2 = lineSegments{
    {1764535160.0, 1562640819.0, 0},   // s2
    {1658825857.0, 1245760131.0, 0}};  // e2

I got the k1=1.0000000000000011, k2=0.99999999999999989. And then I use is_same to check the intersecion point with point P{1658825857.0, 1245760131.0, 0}, it failed. Because the delta length=((e1-s1)*k1+s1-P).length() is 4.76837158203125E-07, which is larger than 1e-10.
How can I fix this bug? Or should I use vector of small length to varify my function?

Typically, you would use a relative error, not absolute, if you have to work with very large numbers. Something like delta.length() < tolerance * x.length() I mean, you could measure a distance between two atoms in a crystal down to a nanometer, but you wouldn't attempt to measure a distance between two cities the same way - your error tolerance should grow with the distance measured.

Welcome to the hell called computational geometry. There is no good solution to this. You can use a relative error instead of an absolute one, but certain algorithms involving line intersections will still fail.

First, as other comments mention, comparing floating point numbers is a difficult topic, but it is required quite often.
In general, when you need to compare two float numbers a and b, you compare their difference to some constant:
abs(a - b)<some_constant

Because of how floating point numbers are represented in memory, it's difficult to just choose a fixed value for some_constant. If you compare very very small numbers, some_constant should be small. But if a and b are very large, some_constant should also increase relative to their magnitude. The reason for this is that even if they are very very close (but not exactly the same), their difference has the same order of magnitude as the numbers, and it's going to be much much larger than a small constant we chose initially.
For this reason, when comparing two numbers, you should ideally multiply a constant by something of a magnitude of the biggest of two numbers:
abs(a - b)<some_constant*abs(max(a,b))

This way you scale a constant to the magnitude of the numbers so it actually makes sense.
What actual valuse can we choose for some_constant? I am not sure, I've seen a lot of different solutions here. Sometimes std::numeric_limit<float>::epsilon() is used, sometimes ...::min(). It's not perfect though, since epsilon is the difference between 1 and the closest representable float number, and min is smallest representable float number. They are very situational because of this. Often I think the best solution would be to choose a constant you feel is relevant to your current task.
This was about comparing two numbers, so what about vector length:
Two issues here. Length is just one number, so what do you compare it against? You can't do abs(a)<abs(a)*some_constant, it doesn't do what we want. Using a fixed predefined constant is also suboptimal. Also, Length is a result of sqrt(sqr(dx)+sqr(dy)+dqr(dz)) so things like floating point errors and difference in magnitude make this less meaningful. Instead what you could do is component based comparison:
abs(dx)<some_constant*mx && abs(dy)<some_constant*my && abs(dz)<some_constant*mz

where mx, my, mz are magnitude multipliers for each dimension: mx=max(x1,x2) etc.
This has a few advantages:
The vectors you compare may have vastly varying magnitude in x than in y, for example, so different constants need to be used for each.
Secondly, it saves you from costly sqrt() operation.
Hope this helps!
